# What is the earliest time to daven maariv during the week?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, maariv, chol-weekday

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When is the earliest time you can daven ma'ariv during the week?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3316/when-is-the-earliest-time-you-can-daven-maariv-during-the-week)

On Shabbos one could accept Shabbos early and thereby daven Maariv early. During the week, when there is no mitzva of Tosfos Shabbos, how early can one daven Maariv?

Comment: I assume you can't get any earlier in the week than Saturday night!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Talmud records two opinions as to the line of demarcation between latest time for reciting Mincha ("afternoon") and Maariv ("evening") prayers:

- Sunset (and yes we can go into questions of observed sunset vs. astronomical sunset, elevations, and so on, but let's assume "sunset" is "sunset.")
- *Plag HaMincha*, i.e. 1.25 relative hours prior to sunset.

Either opinion is acceptable, if followed consistently. (And there's a lot of discussion about what "consistently" means; the Aruch HaShulchan staunchly defends the practice of reciting first Mincha, then Maariv, at some time after *Plag* but before sunset.)

So either *plag* or sunset. It's not about "I hereby accept it as Tuesday" by saying the evening prayers Monday afternoon; it's that it's close enough to Tuesday that I can say the prayers.

However, there's the obligation to recite *Shema* at night; we follow the majority opinion that even if you prayed *Maariv* earlier, you'd have to repeat *Shema* "when the stars come out" -- which Rabbi Moshe Feinstein ruled was 45 minutes after sunset in New York City; it would be more minutes further from the equator, less if you're closer. (But don't be surprised to meet *Rabbeinu Tam* followers who insist on 72 minutes in all sorts of latitudes).

So it's ideal if you could say *Maariv* after "stars-come-out" so you get your Maariv and evening Shema bundled into one; all else being equal, it would probably still be preferable to say *Maariv* oh -- 20 minutes after sunset (which satisfies "stars-come-out" for some rabbis) than immediately after sunset (though either way you'd repeat *Shema* later).