# Time for evening prayer when flying eastward over Greenland and the sun doesn’t set?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, travel, maariv

*(This is the “return" question for my question on [the right time for shaharis when encountering sunrise twice in a day](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67141/time-for-morning-prayer-when-flying-over-greenland-and-seeing-the-sun-rise-twice))*

In the summer, when flying from the East Coast to Tel Aviv on an afternoon flight, there are routes (flying North over Greenland) when the sun never sets. One leaves early afternoon from New York, flies over Greenland by the time evening comes and the sun stays up until morning over Europe.

**In such a case does one need to pray arvit?** Last time I was on such a flight we took a Southern route (middle of the  Atlantic on to Spain) and the night did set so there was no issue. But I was prepared to skip arvit and felt bad in anticipation.

**I could not find anyone addressing the question directly. Do we have sources on the topic or did anyone ask a rav?**

Comment: I took a flight like that the opposite way. Took off just after sunrise at 6am and didn't daven mincha till 26 hours later on the same day. Weird.

Comment: Since when is praying *'Arvit* dependent on the sun setting? Many communities pray *'Arvit* immediately following *Pelag HaMinḥah* when it is still broad daylight.

Comment: @Lee yes but this is only feasible as a minyan, not individually, see e.g., third para [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3316/when-is-the-earliest-time-you-can-daven-maariv-during-the-week)

Comment: @mbloch I may be wrong here, but isn't that talking about davening Mincha after Plag and Maariv before sunset?

Comment: Yeah, I think it should be no problem to daven mincha before plag and maariv afterwards

Comment: @Daniel this is correct in general, in a mynian, but does not apply to the scenario of my question (which had no mynian and no night)

Answer (score 1):

I have now asked different *rabanim* this question since I asked it here. Simple answer is that one is *patur* from *kiriat shema* and *arvit* if one doesn't encounter the night on such a flight.

One interesting answer was offered by [R Ari Wasserman](http://www.workplacehalacha.com/) who told me he personally heard from R Gedalia Finkel (a rav in Mir Yerushalaim and the brother of R Nosson Tzvi Finkel) who asked R Chaim Kanievski if someone should change his flight (at a cost of 700$) to avoid a "night flight with no night" since he would miss *kriat shema*. R Kanievski answered it was worth doing so.

R Wasserman adds this is a *chidush* and a *chumra* of *midat hasidut* since there is no formal obligation.