# Rules for counting the Omer with a bracha if one cannot say arvit on a flight through Greenland

Tags: halacha, blessing, travel, sefirat-ha-omer

In the summer on flights from the US to Europe and Israel (when flying north through Greenland), [there are situations](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67179/time-for-evening-prayer-when-flying-eastward-over-greenland-and-the-sun-doesn-t) where one cannot say *arvit* (the evening's prayer) because it never becomes night outside. One goes straight from evening to morning and the sun never sets.

**In such a situation what are the rules regarding counting the Omer with a *bracha* (blessing) in the morning?**

- Can one count with a bracha because it is the first opportunity one has to do so and since one didn't forget?
- Or should one not say the bracha because one lost the opportunity to do so even if through no fault of his own?

Are there sources addressing the issue directly?

Comment: While I appreciate and identify with fighting for the opportunity to recite a *berakhah*, one could always recite *Sefirat Ha'Omer* without a *berakhah* and nevertheless fulfill his obligation since *berakhot e'inan me'akevot*.

Comment: I don't understand why "first opportunity" and "one didn't forget (!)" are relevant to whether or not the Mitzva only applies at night.

Comment: Since the sun never setting has myriad practical implications, perhaps there should be one master question/answer summarizing how the *poseqim* relate to such a reality.

Comment: @DoubleAA if the bracha applies (1) at the first opportunity one has to count and/or (2) if one didn't forget, then one could say the bracha in the morning. If the bracha applies only at night, then one couldn't. I am not clear on the rules here and am asking for them

Comment: @Lee yes that would be my default behavior indeed (count in the morning without a bracha) if I couldn't find sources allowing to count with a bracha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*BeDi'Avad* if one recited *Sefirat Ha'Omer* **with a berakhah** during *Be'in HaShemashot*, he fulfilled his obligation ([Mishnah Berurah, Siman 489, s.q. 15](http://www.mishnaberurayomi.org/pdf_pages/Chelek_5/1360_Siman_489_Seif_1c-2.pdf) in the name of "Magen Avraham and other *aḥaronim*").

Since there may still well be broad daylight during this time, perhaps one can rely on this opinion while travelling in a part of the world where the sun never sets.

Comment: Can't one fulfill the obligation BeDiAvad without even saying a Berachah?

Comment: @ephraimhelfgot One can, technically, fulfill **any** obligation without reciting a *berakhah*. I don't understand the question.

Comment: @Lee His point is Bedieved doesn't prove anything about if the blessing should have been said.

Comment: @DoubleAA I agree with your and ephraim's logic after having reconsidered my answer. Is it more proper to delete the answer or leave it be for future reference?